# Bash script for-loop with nested if-statement

Tags: bash, for-loop

In my bash script I prompt the user for a desired directory and then loop through the files in that directory to run a command on files who's name matches a certain string. This is a for loop with nested if-statements and I keep receiving errors for syntax or permissions no matter which way I change things up according to other samples I can find on syntax guides and stack overflow.

```
process_files(){
  for i in /home/path/*
  do
    if $i == "string"
    then
        <command>
    fi
  done
}
process_files
```

Comment: `if $i == "string"` is invalid shell syntax.

Comment: You are encouraged to show the errors, and give us an idea of expected results. Examples hould run as-is, ideally.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if [ "$i" = "string" ]
then

...
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do bash if in one line, you need to use ;. E. g., if $i == "string"; then echo "string"; fi. Same for the for-loop.

Comment: This answers a question that wasn't asked without actually identifying the problem.

Comment: In OP's original post, this was a problem.

Comment: No, that was just a formatting problem in the post.

Comment: Well, at least not my problem. :)